# Why does redis cluster suggests at least three masters

Tags: redis

I tried to understand why redis cluster suggests at least three masters. I read
http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial,
https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec
[Redis cluster: 3 master nodes minimum?](https://serverfault.com/questions/815764/redis-cluster-3-master-nodes-minimum)

but they just said I should use three masters without explaining why. Can anybody explain or show me a link about this theorem? And what is the drawback without using at least 3 masters? It is said it is for high availability but again, I do not why.

Comment: Eh? The cluster-spec link explains this in depth.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I went through https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec again and did not see where it explain why 3 masters. Did you mean the section "Availability" in which there is a probability of 1-(1/(N*2-1))? But it did not say anything about how many masters a redis cluster should have. Can you show me exactly which paragraph is about the reason? Thanks